# How to convert this ffmpeg command to a batch command

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, batch, metadata, mp4

I am trying to copy metadata for encoded mp4 files from the source file and I have found this command that does exactly this.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mov -i encoded.mp4 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy encoded_fixed.mp4
```

I would like to write this command to batch process an entire directory but not sure how?

I guess it should start with something like this?

```
for i in *.mov do ???
```

Comment: not just ffmpeg. any command

Comment: `for %f in (*.txt) do @echo dfg %f  fdf` <-- when you have what you want then remove @echo